# How to inspect a CustomAction's property (Wix)?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I am trying to put together a small 'prerequisites' dialog in Wix to give confidence to the users that they have all of the required things needed to run my software:

For example, I have a need for Managed DirectX, so I look for some DLLs:

```
<Property Id="MANAGED_DIRECTX">
  <DirectorySearch Path="$(env.SystemRoot)\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0" Depth="0" Id="MDXDir">
    <FileSearch Name="Microsoft.DirectX.dll"/>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<Property Id="MANAGED_DIRECTX_DIRECTINPUT">
  <DirectorySearch Path="$(env.SystemRoot)\Microsoft.NET\DirectX for Managed Code\1.0.2902.0" Depth="0" Id="MDXInputDir">
    <FileSearch Name="Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput.dll"/>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

I also have a CustomAction to combine my condition logic:

```
<CustomAction Id="SetManagedDirectXInstalled"
              Property="MANAGED_DIRECTX_INSTALLED"
              Value="NOT([MANAGED_DIRECTX] = '') AND NOT ([MANAGED_DIRECTX_DIRECTINPUT] = ''")/>
```

This CustomAction is sequenced:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetManagedDirectXInstalled" After="AppSearch" />
  <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

What I should now be able to do is use "MANAGED DIRECTX INSTALLED" to do something, e.g.

```
    <Control Id="NoManagedDirectX" Type="Text" X="20" Y="50" Width="300" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes">
      <Text>Microsoft Managed DirectX (MDX) for DirectX 9.0 is NOT installed</Text>
      <Condition Action="show">NOT MANAGED_DIRECTX_INSTALLED</Condition>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="ManagedDirectX" Type="Text" X="20" Y="50" Width="300" Height="60" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Hidden="yes">
      <Text>Microsoft Managed DirectX (MDX) for DirectX 9.0 is correctly installed</Text>
      <Condition Action="show">MANAGED_DIRECTX_INSTALLED</Condition>
    </Control>
```

It doesn't matter what I do, the condition is always false (e.g. not installed) even when I know the files are there.  Using the msiexec command with /l*vx does not show the MANAGED DIRECTX INSTALLED property anywhere.

When a <Condition> is used with the following, it successfully prevents installation (although I no longer want to block installs in this case, just advise).

```
<Condition Message="You must have Microsoft Managed DirectX (MDX) for DirectX 9.0 installed">
  MANAGED_DIRECTX AND MANAGED_DIRECTX_DIRECTINPUT
</Condition>
```

How can I trace/debug this (or what have I done wrong?)

---

***EDIT*** - I'm now certain that my CustomAction is not even being called, setting it to the following is not showing expected results either!

```
<CustomAction Id='SetManagedDirectXInstalled'
              Property='MANAGED_DIRECTX_INSTALLED'
              Value='Something hard-coded'/>
```

or

```
<CustomAction Id='SetManagedDirectXInstalled'
              Error='Some error should show!'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer, but I can't try it until I'm next at my development PC.

It appears I have to compare the values to TRUE/FALSE (or empty string) not just expecting it to work as boolean ([Source](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson5.php#expression))

> In these expressions, you can use
>   property names (remember that they are
>   case sensitive). Non-existent property
>   names will be treated as empty
>   strings. The logical value of a
>   property reflects whether it has been
>   set—meaning that you cannot check for
>   a logical value by simply using the
>   property:
>
> - PROPERTY
>     This will evaluate to true if the property has been set and has any
>     value, even if this value is false.
> - NOT PROPERTY
>     This will evaluate to true if the property has not been set at all.
> - PROPERTY = TRUE
> - PROPERTY = FALSE
>     This is the proper way to check the value of a logical property.

Answer (score 3):

1. To debug, use a verbose log file. It will show you the states of your Properties as they change. You should then be able to evaluate the Condition with that knowledge
2. I answered this same question not too long ago here. A Condition that uses the Property name is a test for existence. An existence test for a Property evaluates to true if the Property has any value at all. If you want to check the value of a Property you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: I'm running with the /l*vx command line argument but the CustomAction set property doesn't show!

Comment: I have tried adding the following, but it's still always blank (even though the two bits inside are not!
Value="NOT ([MANAGED_DIRECTX] = &quot;&quot;) AND NOT ([MANAGED_DIRECTX_DIRECTINPUT] = &quot;&quot;)"

Comment: Even a CustomAction setting the property to [MANAGED_DIRECTX] (not-blank) and no attempt at boolean logic results in a blank property!  Is the square-bracket convention correct?

Comment: I am not convinced at all that the CustomAction is ever being called, nothing mentions it in the log and I can see no side-effect of the call even if I simply put Value="Hello" !

Comment: Did you schedule the CustomAction in the appropriate sequence?

Comment: See the InstallExecuteSequence in the original question... that is, I think, how you schedule CA's isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but is it ending up in your MSI? At this point, I must admit, I'm very confused by what you are trying to do here. Looking very closely, it looks like you're trying to have a Property that contains characters commonly used in Conditions to be evaluated as Conditions. I don't think the Windows Installer works that way. But I can't explain why your CustomAction/@Error example doesn't work either. There isn't enough information in the text above to state for sure what the problem is now... I'm just guessing.